# Android: Premature end of JPEG

Tags: android, file-upload, jpeg, bitmapfactory

I have to send to a server a few JPEG files taken form camera. Of course they are to big to do it simply by file stream. My code (for each file) looks as follow:

```
struct3.put("type", "image/jpeg");
f = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];
bis.read(buffer);
fis.close();
struct3.put("bits", buffer);
```

After all I send a struct:

```
Object[] params3 = { bid, login, pass, struct3 };
Object response2 = client.send("my_function", params3);
```

When I send small files all is correct, but when files are bigger I received "Out of Memory Exception".

My solution of that is to compress JPEG files:

```
struct3.put("type", "image/jpeg");
final Options opts = new Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, opts);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream); 
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
struct3.put("bits", byteArray);
Object[] params3 = { bid, login, pass, struct3 };
Object response2 = client.send("my_function", params3);
```

But that way produced an error ON THE SERVER SIDE:
"Premature End of JPEG file".

Is there any way to correct the JPEG file before sending it?
I know that JPEG shoud end with EOI ( 0xff, 0xfd).

How to check it and make a corrections?

Comment: it means your  code is not compressing the jpeg files could you please send us log cat report.

Comment: There is no log cat report due to photos are uploaded to WordPress and only track is warning from gdlib. The warning contains: "Premature End of JPEG file"

Answer (score 2):

There is no log cat report due to photos are uploaded to WordPress and only track is warning from gdlib. The warning contains: "Premature End of JPEG file"

Although I solved the problem. I've implemented procedure checking if byteArray ends with 0xFF,0xD9 and in case is not I add two bytes:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
int byteToSendSize = byteArray.length;
boolean proper = ((byteArray[byteArray.length-2])==((byte)0xff)) 
    && ((byteArray[byteArray.length-1])==((byte)0xd9));
if(!proper)
byteToSendSize +=2;
byte[] byteToSend = new byte[byteToSendSize];

for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
byteToSend[i] = byteArray[i];
}
if(!proper){
  byteToSend[byteArray.length] = (byte) 0xff;
  byteToSend[byteArray.length+1] = (byte) 0xd9;
}
struct3.put("bits", byteToSend);
```

Comment: Had a problem with decoding some of jpeg images through BitmapFactory::decode.
And now with your patching for input stream works like a charm!